# Menu that fit to the buttom/top of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I saw a cool style/js function (I can tell what it is) that implemented on a side menu.
You know the situation when you have a long center page and one of / both of you sides ends and that leave a blank space? Well this site implemented this thing that just when the user scrool to the place where the side menu end - the menu get absolute postion and doesnt move.

How can I do this?

If you want to see an example you can look [here](http://mazaltov.walla.co.il/Search/Service.aspx?ServiceTypeID=667) (just scroll and look on the sides)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can achieve similar effect using this: http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/keep-element-in-view-while-scrolling-using-jquery/comment-page-1/ (just making it move with `0` as speed parameter instead of `slow`, as in the [example](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/wp-content/demos/jquery-scrolling-element/)) and adding conditions about whether the current position fits within the box it is displayed (you can take height of the box - menu being moved on page or box that contains the menu - by using [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) jQuery function).

**EDIT:**

The page you referenced uses the following JavaScript code to support what you try to accomplish:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var seoHeight =  $$('dvIndexSeoMaster').height();
            seoHeight = (seoHeight > 0) ?  seoHeight : 0; 
        var documentHeight = $(document.body).height() - 120 - seoHeight;
        var fixedMode = false;
        var hasFixedClass = false;
        var leftColElm = $sc('dvFixed');
        var leftColPos = leftColElm.offset().top;
        var leftColHeight = leftColElm.height();
        var rightColElm = $$('dvIndexMasterRightCol');
        var rightColPos = rightColElm.offset().top;
        var rightColHeight = rightColElm.height();
        function scrollElm(elmPos,elmHeight,objElm, cssClass){
            var fixedMode = false;
            var hasFixedClass = false;
            var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            (windowTop >= elmPos && (windowTop + elmHeight) < documentHeight) ? fixedMode = true : fixedMode = false;
            if( fixedMode){
                $(objElm).addClass(cssClass);
                hasFixedClass = true;
            }else if( (fixedMode == false)){
                $(objElm).removeClass(cssClass);
                hasFixedClass = false;
            }
        };
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            scrollElm(leftColPos,leftColHeight,leftColElm,'make-fixed');
            scrollElm(rightColPos,rightColHeight,rightColElm, 'make-fixed');
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the `make-fixed` CSS class has the following definition:

```
.make-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an element stay in the same place, even as the user scrolls, with the CSS `position:fixed` property: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning